# Removing brackets for multi value Param URIs when using to_query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to build a URI with a parameter with multiple values. i.e.:

```
facet.field=a&facet.field=b&facet.field=c
```

If I do it this way:

```
uri = {:'facet.field' => ['a', 'b', 'c']}.to_query
```

I'll get:

```
facet.field[]=a&facet.field[]=b&facet.field[]=c
```

How do I get rid of the brackets?

P.S. I'm writing a query against Solr and the URI with brackets doesn't return the facets as I expect to.

Comment: I thought there might be a more elegant way? :D

Comment: Like what? you want to remove the '[]' from a string, I'm not sure what you're looking for here :)

Comment: ~injekt, not building the [] in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
URI.encode_www_form('facet.field' => ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```